# Почему GlobalFree такой медленный?

Tags: c++, memory-management

пример

```
char str[51]="01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789";
LPVOID* a=GlobalAlloc(GPTR,1000000);
for(DWORD i=0;i<1000000;i++)
{
    a[i]=GlobalAlloc(GPTR,51)
    memcpy(a[i],str,50)
}

for(DWORD i=0;i<1000000;i++)
GlobalFree(a[i]);
```

в этом коде замерял тиккаунт на первый цикл тратится 2500 а на второй 120000.

Comment: Исходя из названия, я бы не ожидал скорости от этой функции. (А кстати, почему не `malloc` или `new`?)

Comment: так исторически сложилось :) сейчас начал оптимизировать очень старую прогу нашел вот это тормозное место. уже замерил со стрингами все выйдет намного быстрее. Но может быть есть вариант ускорить то что есть, без переделываний. У меня просто в голове не укладывается почему выделить и заполнить работает в 50 раз быстрее чем просто освободить

Comment: GlobalAlloc/GlobalFree на самом деле делает системные запросы. А они "дорогие". То что Вас кажется, что GlobalFree должен быть быстрее - далеко не факт.

Правильный подход - выделять память одним куском, а не сотнями мелкими.

Comment: ...Что, собственно, и делает рантайм. Потом полученный кусок раздаётся по частям тем, кто вызывает `malloc`.

Comment: куски могут меняться в т.ч. по длине. И это, я уже нашел как оптимизировать (string), вопрос скорее теоретический почему так происходит. Может опция в настройках компилятора какая есть. Или переделать на Local .... . Virtual... наверное не стоит ибо скушает он очень много памяти

Comment: KoVadim уже ответил почему - системные вызовы. Почитайте про них. Вкратце - делается переключение из юзерспейса в ядро. Это дорого.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Историческая справка:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34326835/localalloc-vs-globalalloc-vs-malloc-vs-new
перевод: http://www.transl-gunsmoker.ru/2009/10/localalloc-globalalloc.html

Если вкратце, то в бородатые времена была сегментарная память, глобальная и локальная кучи, селекторы и ближние и дальние указатели. Потом (с выходом Win 9x, а последствии NT) перешли на "плоскую" модель памяти, разделение указателей на селекторы, ближние и дальние указатели кануло в лета, но обратная совместимость осталась.

Настоящее описано тут:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366533(v=vs.85).aspx

И настоящее гласит, что современные ОС не обеспечивают разделение на глобальную и локальную кучи, в результате чего группы функций Global и Local суть одно и тоже и выбор между ними - дело личных предпочтений (если конечно вы не пишите под вин16).
Более того, переход от сегментарной модели памяти к виртуальной сделал часть функций бессмысленными (т.к. больше нету селекторов и ближних указателей).

В другой статье https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366596(v=vs.85).aspx написано, что объекты, память под которые выделена через функции GlobalAlloc или LocalAlloc, располагаются на частных, фиксированных страницах памяти с доступом чтения/записи, однако недоступны для других процессов.
Также там упоминается, что размер выделяемой физической памяти может быть БОЛЬШЕ запрашиваемого, а для определения реально выделенного размера следует использовать функции GlobalSize и LocalSize.
Кроме того, там же написано и об огромном оверхэде функций Global и Local, так что их использование в современном мире крайне не рекомендуется (кроем случаев разработки под соотв. платформы).

Что касается скорости работы освобождения памяти, то тут вопрос сложный и неоднозначный, т.к. что там делает ядро ОС при вызове GlobalFree известно только индусам, это ядро писавшим.

Если вы делали замеры в дебаге и msvc, то необходимо выставить _NO_DEBUG_HEAP=1 в настройках окружения (Environment) студии, т.к. дебаг использует абсолютно другую реализацию выделения памяти для отладки.